# Identifying old car

Tags: vehicle-identification

Can someone help me to identify this car? The picture is from around 1950s or 60s, taken in Sweden. Other cars in the same image have been identified as Volvo PV444, Saab 92 and Opel Kapitän. I've searched the internet but not found any car that looks the same (Austin, Morris, Ford). [image]

Comment: Its a mob hit car, the trunk is open, ready for a body......

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Maybe a Russian car?

Comment: I miss those draft windows.

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 - have you ever seen an Austin A40?

Comment: Too short to be a PA Cresta.

Comment: [This](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/0c/Austin_A40_%28Farina%29_Mk_I_reg_ca_1960.JPG) is what a late 1950s/early 60s Austin A40 looks like. Some people call it 'the first hatchback'. They never made a 4 door version.

Answer (score 2):

I recognised it straight away. It's a Rootes Group model. Could be a Hillman Super Minx, Singer Vogue, or Humber Sceptre from 1961 to 1964. Like many UK motor groups formed by takeovers, they used different brands to target different sections of the market - Hillman was the base model, Singer was more sporty, Humber was more luxurious.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I would add that "sporty" and "luxurious" are relative terms here. This is a fairly dull family car, whatever the 'rim level' as people say now.